# can't run BottlePy

Tags: python, bottle

I'm quite a newbie with Python and BottlePy, so this question might seem dumb. I can't run my BottlePy-file, as the Python-window disappears when it should run BottlePy. 
Does anyone know why Python doesn't run my code?

This is my BottlePy code (I use Notepad++ to edit the codes)

```
from bottle import response, error, get
import json



@get('/hello')
def hello_world():
'''Responds to http://localhost:8080/hello with an example JSON object
'''
response_body = {'Hello': 'World'}

# This returns valid JSON in the response, but does not yet set the 
# associated HTTP response header.  This you should do yourself in your 
# own routes! 
return json.dumps(response_body)

@get('/db-example')
def db_example(db):
'''Responds with names of all products in Amsterdam

Add a parameter 'db' to your function to get a database cursor from
WtPlugin. The parameter db is of type sqlite3.Cursor. Documentation is
at https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor

If you want to start with a clean sheet, delete the file 'inventory.db'.
It will be automatically re-created and filled with one example item.

Access this route at http://localhost:8080/db-example
'''
# Execute SQL statement to select the name of all items located in A'dam
db.execute("SELECT name FROM inventory WHERE location=?", ('Amsterdam',))

# Get all results in a list of dictionaries
names = db.fetchall() # Use db.fetchone() to get results one by one

# TODO: set the appropriate HTTP headers and HTTP response codes.

# Return results as JSON
return json.dumps(names)


@error(404)
def error_404_handler(e):

# Content type must be set manually in error handlers
response.content_type = 'application/json'

return json.dumps({'Error': {'Message': e.status_line, 'Status': e.status_code}})


if __name__ == "__main__":
from bottle import install, run
from wtplugin import WtDbPlugin, WtCorsPlugin

install(WtDbPlugin())
install(WtCorsPlugin())
run(host='localhost', port=8080, reloader=True, debug=True, autojson=False)
```

Comment: You have to check your code: under `@get(/hello)` it must be  a function definition: edit or better remove it.

Comment: i changed it: it has now "response_body" as output. But it still doesn't work...

Comment: You need to be more specific than "doesn't run." What output are you seeing?

Comment: Your `hello_world` function must return something (like an array of strings, or a dict) for a response to be sent. `return ['hello world']` or `return {'hello': 'world'}`

Comment: This isn't syntactically valid python. Your function bodies need to be indented.